# Installing Ubuntu with WSL - Error Parameter incorrect

Tags: system-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying to install WSL and Ubuntu on my Windows laptop. My laptop is running on Win 10 Home with OS build 19045.2486.

As I follow the instruction from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

I open the  Windows Command Prompt in administrator mode and run the following code:

```
wsl --install
```

After it installed, I restarted my laptop successfully.

However, after I restarted my laptop and try to launch Ubuntu from WSL terminal. It failed to launch and give me this error

[image]

After that it just closed everything automatically.

When I try to launch the Ubuntu app from the Microsoft store, no thing responded.

When I check the version of WSL and Ubuntu in Cmd:

[image]

I wonder how do I solve this error and enable Ubuntu with WSL?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  If you search the Windows Start menu for "Ubuntu", does anything come up?  If so, does it say "Ubuntu 22.04", just "Ubuntu", or something else?  Thanks!

Comment: Regardless, I think I'd start by trying to uninstall whatever comes up in the Start menu (if anything).  Just right-click on the Ubuntu (or variant) and *Uninstall*.  Then try installing Ubuntu from the Store again and see if you get a different result.

Comment: hi, I have already done that. I tried to install it from the store and the app wont launch. Then I try to launch from the CMD and the probelm remains.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be running into [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2577).  The running theory in that issue is that there's a problem with your user's permissions to run Store applications.  It may not affect all Store apps, but it definitely hits WSL for some users.

The best workaround is probably to try:

```
wsl --install --web-download Ubuntu
```

You may need to remove the existing Store version (again) first.

An alternative workaround for a lot of users in that Github issue is to copy the files from the directory referenced above to a new directory such as `C:\Ubuntu`.  Running `ubuntu.exe` from the new location seems to work based on most reports (plenty of thumbs-ups, etc. on that comment in the issue).

However, this may require gaining access to the protected `C:\WindowsApps` folder.  This isn't necessarily recommended, which is why I'd try the `--web-download` option first.